# Find duplicates and their indexes

Tags: python, arrays

I need to write a program using parallel arrays. The program should ask the user to input a name then it will check if the name is in an existing array and if the name is in the array it will return the first name, the last name, the index where it was found in the array and the phone number. If there is more than a name that matches then it will return both of the names and their indexes.
This is what I have so far but I cannot seem to figure out how to get the index of the second duplicate.

```
name = ["David", "Tony", "Josh", "Chloe", "David", "Olivia"]
lastName = ["Smith", "Jones", "Brown", "Miller", "Brown", "Williams"]
phone = ["111-123-1234","222-123-1234","333-123-1234","444-123-1234","555-123-1234","662-123-1234"]
for i in range(len(name)):
    sName = input("Enter a Name: ")
    if sName in name:
        index = firstName.index(sName)
        print(name[index],lastName[index],"is located at index",index)
        print("Phone number:", phone[index])
        print()
    else:
        print("The name:", sName, "does not exist in our records")
        print("Please try a different name.")
        print()

#The output should be something like: 
#David Smith is located at index 0 
#Phone number: 111-123-1234
#
#David Brown is located at index 4 
#Phone number:555-123-1234
```

Comment: If you find any helpful post upvote and hit the tick mark.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple solution to your problem.

```
name = ["David", "Tony", "Josh", "Chloe", "David", "Olivia"]
lastName = ["Smith", "Jones", "Brown", "Miller", "Brown", "Williams"]
phone = ["111-123-1234","222-123-1234","333-123-1234","444-123-1234","555-123-1234","662-123-1234"]


found = False
sName = input("Enter a Name: ")

for i in range(len(name)):
    if sName == name[i]:
        print(name[i],lastName[i],"is located at index",i)
        print("Phone number:", phone[i])
        found = True

if found == False:
    print("The name:", sName, "does not exist in our records")
    print("Please try a different name.")
```

You do not need to use the index function because as you iterate the list using the for loop, if the target name is found a name[i], that value of i is the index of the target name. Additionally I moved

```
sName = input("Enter a Name: ")
```

outside the for loop. If it remains in the for loop, it only compares the target name with   the name at the current index i.

Answer (score 0):

In Python list `index` method, you can specify additional arguments:

`start`: from which index to start searching

`end`: upto which index should the item be searched

Once you find the first index, you can try searching again by setting `start` index just after the first occurrence index.

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that could the job:

```
name = ["David", "Tony", "Josh", "Chloe", "David", "Olivia"]
lastName = ["Smith", "Jones", "Brown", "Miller", "Brown", "Williams"]
phone = ["111-123-1234","222-123-1234","333-123-1234","444-123-1234","555-123-1234","662-123-1234"]

def findIndex(find_name, first_name):
    pos = []
    for x in range(len(first_name)):
        if find_name == first_name[x]:
            pos.append(x)
    
    return pos


for i in range(len(name)):
    sName = input("Enter a Name: ")
    pos = findIndex(sName, name)
    if len(pos) > 0:
        for x in pos:
            print(name[x],lastName[x],"is located at index",x)
            print("Phone number:", phone[x])
            print()
            
    else:
        print("The name:", sName, "does not exist in our records")
        print("Please try a different name.")
        print()
```

Here is a more pythonic function:

```
def findIndex(find_name, first_name):

    return [x for x in range(len(first_name)) if find_name == first_name[x]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this using the `enumerate` function:

```
lastName = ["Smith", "Jones", "Brown", "Miller", "Brown", "Williams"]
phone = ["111-123-1234","222-123-1234","333-123-1234","444-123-1234","555-123-1234","662-123-1234"]

sample_name = 'David Smith'

def find_details(full_name):
    
    # Split the full name into first and last name
    [first, last] = full_name.split(' ')
    
    # check for the first name in the name list
    for count, f_name in enumerate(name):
        
        # if the first name is listed
        if f_name == first:
            
            # check if the last name at the same index is the last name we need
            if lastName[count] == last:
                
                phone_number = phone[count]
                
                # we have found the person we need
                print(f'{full_name} is located at position {count}. \nPhone number: {phone_number}\n')
                return True
        
    # Otherwise, we didn't find the name
    print(f"The name: {full_name} does not exist in our records. \nPlease try a different name.\n")
    return False
    
find_details('Josh Brown')

find_details('Delilah Le')
```